# How to create PHP method linking?

Tags: php, object, method-chaining

I've seen other objects that do this:

```
$obj->method1()->method2();
```

How do I do that? Is each function just modifying the pointer of an object or returning a pointer?

I don't know the proper term for this style -- if anyone could help me with that, it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is achieved by returning `$this` at the end of each function, thus giving a chainable reference.

```
class MyClass {
    public function method1() {
        //...
        return $this;
    }
    public function method2() {
        //...
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the same way, if I return another object, it can also be chained? In my specific case I'm returning a MySQLi prepared statement, which I suppose I could then immediately do a bind_param on?

Comment: Yes. Just keep in mind that having a lot of different objects being returned in a chain can make your API quite confusing to use. It might be worth typing in the extra line instead of transferring the chain to another object.

Answer (score 4):

Fluid interface.

Simply set your object's method1() to return $this

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a Person class. You will have your methods doing something like that:

```
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this; // We now return $this (the Person)
}
```

Download Zend Framework and check some part of the code - you can learn a lot from there.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to this as method chaining. See http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Method-Chaining-in-PHP-5/1/

also inside your method

```
public function method1()
   // do stuff

   return $this;
}
```